# Using keyof Type to lookup property on Type

Tags: typescript

I have the following types

```js
type Type = {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: someOtherType
}
type Props = keyof Type
```

now I know you can use an "indexed access type" to get the type of propN, i.e. `type Num = Type["prop1"]`, however I would like to use the following in a function

```js
function(p: Props) {
    // ...
    let something = somethingElse as Type[p]
    // Typescript can't infer the type
    // ...
}
```

so that when i call

```js
let a = function("prop1");
// a should be of type number
```

However that is not possible, and throws

```js
'p' refers to a value, but is being used as a type here. Did you mean 'typeof p'?
```

however if I use `typeof p`, then `Type[typeof p]` gives me the union type `number | string | someOtherType`.

Is there some way to fix this. I have tried to look at using generices, but it doesn't seem possible.

Comment: What's wrong with this? `Props` is key of Type (`"prop1" | "prop2" | "prop3"`), hence the type from `Type[typeof p]` / `Type[Props]` is `number | string | someOtherType`. What's the expected type of `something`?

Comment: Sorry, I edited it, but the below answer solves it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I think what you are trying to achieve can be done using a generic function like so:

```
function foo<T extends keyof Type>(p: T) {
    let something = somethingElse as T
}
```

Answer (score 1):

More complete example:

```
type ValueOf<T> = T[keyof T];

type Type = {
    prop1: number;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: boolean;
}

type Props = keyof Type;

function foo<T extends Props>(p: T): Type[T] {
    let something = "";
    return something as Type[T];
}

const a = foo("prop1"); // a is number
const b = foo("prop2"); // b is string
const c = foo("prop3"); // c is boolean
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `typeof p` you get the Typescript type of the Javascript variable `p`.  You have said right here `function(p: Props)` that the type of `p` is `Props`.  That type means that it can be any of the keys of `Props`.

You **must** use a generic if you want your code to know *which* key `p` is.  Otherwise that information is discarded and the type of `p` is widened to `Props` by `function(p: Props)`.

You can use your indexed access type assertion if the type of `p` is generic.

```
function myFunc<P extends Props>(p: P) {
    // ...
    let something = somethingElse as Type[P]
    // Typescript can't infer the type
    // ...
}
```

But you might not even need to assert with `as` if everything is typed properly.

```
type Type = {
  prop1: number;
  prop2: string;
}
type Props = keyof Type

function myFunc<P extends Props>(p: P) {
  const type: Type = { prop1: 0, prop2: "" };
  return type[p]; // type is inferred as `Type[P]`
}

const one = myFunc("prop1"); // type number
const two = myFunc("prop2"); // type string
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/w18PAW)